# Non-apple keyboard connect with cable getting stuck on sleep

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake, compatibility

I am using a Mac Mini M1 (2020) and I have a Ducky 2087 keyboard connected via USB.

The keyboard works fine while active, but when I leave the Mini alone for some time, around 10-15 minutes or more, when I try logging back in, there's no keyboard input received. They keyboard's LEDs are lit, but it's like it's not connected.

My only solution has been to disconnect/reconnect the keyboard and it works.

If I don't leave the Mac idle the keyboard works without any issues.

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

The OS is Ventura 13.1 (22C65), Mac Mini M1 16 GB RAM 256 SSD.

Comment: Try changing the USB port. Is it plugged in directly to the mini or through a hub?

Comment: It's plugged directly to the USB-A ports. So I don't think switching it would make any difference.

Comment: It does.  Apple will designate a “primary” port that always has power while the other ports get their power turned off during sleep.  Besides, what could it hurt to try?

Comment: @Allan I'll try doing that, but this sounds like a terrible idea. Is there a way to change (enable/disable) this? Because on the other USB-A port is my mouse receiver... and I fear the same thing might happen.

Comment: If you click a button on the mouse, does it wake the computer and enable the keyboard?

Comment: It wakes the computer, but doesn't enable the keyboard. I switched the keyboard to the other port and I'm gonna try to see if that changes something.